# Character input in a array and accessing by array index

Tags: perl

To solve a problem of `subsequence check` **I am trying to take two string input in two different array and access them by array indexs ?**

In **C** i did it like below..

```
char text[25000],pattern[25000];
scanf("%s %s",text,pattern);
```

and i can access each character through array index.

**How can i do the same in perl??**

In perl i haven't found anything specific to access array indexes. All i got is to use the perl `split` function..

```
my @pattern = split(" ",<>);
```

This splits the input based on space and assigns to array indexes, if the input is like `canada nad` split will assign `canada` to **$pattern[0]** and `nad` to **$pattern[1]**

**but i want them in two separate array?**

i found another user of split like..

```
my @pattern = split(undef,<>);
foreach my $val (@pattern){
     print $val."\n";
}
```

this can access all the character of the string but the problem is i can't assign them in two different arrays.

**Thanks in advance of any idea/suggestion.**

### Got it, i was looking for something like this..

```
my ($text,$pattern) = split(' ',<>);
my @textarr= split //,$text;
my @patterarr= split //,$pattern;
```

Comment: You probably don't need them to be in an array. You can use [`substr`](http://p3rl.org/substr) to access a single character in a string `perl -E'my $text = "text"; say substr($text,2,1)'` (prints `x`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you want

```
# Two strings (which are scalars, not arrays)
my $text = "canada";
my $pattern = "nad";
```

or

```
# Two array of single-char strings
my @text_chars = ("c", "a", "n", "a", "d", "a");
my @pattern    = ("n", "a", "d");
```

If you want the former,

```
my ($text, $pattern) = split(' ', $line);
```

If you want the the latter, follow up with

```
my @text_chars    = split //, $text;
my @pattern_chars = split //, $pattern;
```

The latter can also be achieved using the following if you don't mind dealing with references to arrays:

```
my ($text_chars, $pattern_chars) = map [ split // ], split ' ', $line;
```

In the above, `$line` is produced using

```
chomp( my $line = <> );
```

Comment: I want the later one and the solution works but have a little issue :)
I tested it like below..

my $text=<>;   
my @text_arr=split(//,$text);
print @text_arr."\n";
foreach my $val (@text_arr){
     print $val."\n";
}

It count the `newline` and the end.How to avoid that?

Comment: you can `chomp` each `$text` line first to remove the new line character before you split

Comment: Updated to handle newline.